# ¿como actualizar Xampp desde Linux Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xampp

Por favor alguien me pone los comandos para actualizar xampp desde Linux Ubuntu Mate. Nunca tengo problemas en instalar, porque siempre hay muchos tutoriales y manuales donde explican paso a paso, pero no encuentro ninguno que explique como actualzar. Y siempre tengo que esperarme hasta cuando cambio de compu o sistema operativo para volver a instalar, y mientras mi xampp siempre anda desactualizado.

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1):

Asegúrese de agregar el repositorio XAAMP:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:upubuntu-com/xampp
```

A continuación, actualice con:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: gracias. ¿sabes como podria llegar a mi panel xampp? es que cuando pongo "localhost" me salen las carpetas de mis paginas creadas, pero recuerdo que antes salia un panel, con mi baste de datos, etc.. necesito llegar ahi para verificar que este actualizado todo, phpadmin, marisql, php, etc

Comment: O sea cuando pongo "localhost" ya no me sale la página naranja de xampp, desde donde se podía entrar a phpmyadmin y todo, sino que sale mi carpeta de páginas creadas, y dicen "index of"